# Injecting Spring Dependencies into ConstrantValidator

Tags: spring, bean-validation

I'm using Bean Validation.  I have a custom validator `@MyValidator` that needs to look up a value with an injected Spring managed DAO object. How can I get access to this?  Spring isn't injecting the DAO into my "MyValidator" object.

```
@Component
public class CodeListValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CodeList, String> {
    @Autowired
    private ICodeListCommonService codeListCommonService;

    private CodeListEnum codeListID;

    @Override
    public void initialize(CodeList constraintAnnotation) {
        this.codeListID = constraintAnnotation.value();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return codeListCommonService.doesCodeEntityExistForCodeList(codeListID.getDbCodeListId(), value, ProviderConstants.CODE_LIST_STATUS_ACTIVE);
    }
}
```

The "codeListCommonService" is null.  This is because Spring isn't creating the class - but how can I get this to work with Spring AoP?

The use of this validator looks like this:

```
        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

        MyObject validateMe = new MyObject();

        Set<ConstraintViolation<MyObject>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(validateMe);
```

For MyObject:

```
public class MyObject {
   @Size(max = 1)
   @CodeList(CodeListEnum.CARTYPE)
   public String carType;
}
```

So when the validator runs, it processes the annotations... I just need to get a service injected into the CodeListValidator I made to it can do a DB lookup to verify the value against the DB list of "valid car type values".

**EDIT: The solution:**

Played around with the idea of making a Spring aware factory- too much integration with existing code.

The solution that seems the best (and it works here) is to make a Spring service that stores the ApplicationContext in a static method so "non-Spring managed" beans can get to them.

So a new service:

```
@Service
public class SpringApplicationContextService implements ISpringApplicationContextService, ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return applicationContext;
    }
}
```

And then any validator or non-Spring bean can get at the Spring beans via:

```
public class CodeListValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CodeList, String> {
    @Autowired
    private ICodeListCommonService codeListCommonService;

    private CodeListEnum codeListID;

    @Override
    public void initialize(CodeList constraintAnnotation) {
        this.codeListID = constraintAnnotation.value();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        ICodeListCommonService codeListCommonService = SpringApplicationContextService.getApplicationContext().getBean(ICodeListCommonService.class);
        return codeListCommonService.doesCodeEntityExistForCodeList(codeListID.getDbCodeListId(), value, ProviderConstants.CODE_LIST_STATUS_ACTIVE);
    }
}
```

And, of course, the reason for all of this (which is used dozens of times in this app):

```
    @CodeList(CodeListEnum.EMAIL_OPT_OUT_FLAG)
    public String emailOptOutFlag;

    @CodeList(CodeListEnum.CLEARING_HOUSE)
    public String clearingHouse;
```

Comment: You may have to post some more code,  `MyValidator` is unknown and where are you trying to autowire `MyValidator` ?

Comment: I'm making my own validator- I have other ones working, but this one would require an injected Spring service.  I see the problem- the validators come from a factory it would seem that would have to be "Spring aware"... adding more code

Answer (score 3):

The minimum setup for `@Autowired` to work properly in `ConstraintValidator` implementation is to have this bean in a Spring `@Configuration`:

```java
    @Bean
    public Validator defaultValidator() {
        return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
    }
```

This allows any beans, including `ApplicationContext`, to be injected directly into a `ConstraintValidator`:

```java
@Constraint(validatedBy = DemoValidator.class)
public @interface DemoAnnotation {
    // ...
    Class<?> beanClass();
}

public class DemoValidator implements ConstraintValidator<DemoAnnotation, String> {

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private Object bean;

    @Autowired
    public DemoValidator(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(DemoAnnotation constraint) {
        Class<?> beanClass = constraint.beanClass();
        bean = applicationContext.getBean(beanClass);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String obj, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return !obj.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://github.com/Martin-BG/Autowired-in-ConstraintValidator)

For a really flexible validation solution I would recommend **Jakub Jirutka's** [Bean Validator utilizing Spring Expression Language (SpEL)](https://github.com/jirutka/validator-spring) which allows things like:

```java
public class Sample {

    @SpELAssert("@myService.calculate(#this) > 42")
    private int value;
}
```