# How to perform an @Entity query inside a ConstraintValidator

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-validator

The scenario is that before persisting a `Log` entity class, its property, `String description` should be checked if it contains at least a word found in the `IllegalWord` entity class. Here is the mapping of the two entity classes:

```
// Log.java
@Entity
public class Log {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @NotContainingIllegalWords
    private String description;
}

// IllegalWord.java
@Entity
public class IllegalWord {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String word;
}
```

Since I will be performing a `select *` to the `IllegalWord` entity class, I created a repository class for it:

```
// IllegalWordRepository.java
@Repository
public interface IllegalWordRepository extends CrudRepository<IllegalWord, Long> {}
```

And then created the `ConstraintValidator` validator class that will be used by `NotContainingIllegalWords` annotation, that in turn, will be use to annotate the `String description` field of `Log` entity class:

```
// NotContainingIllegalWordsValidator.java
public class NotContainingIllegalWordsValidator implements ConstraintValidator<NotContainingIllegalWords, Object> {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NotContainingIllegalWordsValidator.class);

    @Autowired
    private IllegalWordRepository illegalWordRepository;
    
    public void initialize(NotContainingIllegalWords constraintAnnotation) {}

    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext cxt) {
        log.debug("illegalWordRepository is null? " + (illegalWordRepository == null));
        // Returns "illegalWordRepository is null? true"
        // It is not injected even with the @Autowired annotation.

        boolean valid = true;
        
        Collection<IllegalWord> illegalWords = illegalWordRepository.findAll();
        // Encounters a NullPointerException here.
        
        // valid = ...loop through illegalWords collection and match regex (or whatever optimal approach)
        // with @param value to check if it contains the illegal word.
        
        return valid;
    }
```

I thought it will be as straight-forward like that. But the statement `illegalWordRepository.findAll()` throws an error because the `illegalWordRepository` variable is null. Notice that I tried to check if it is `null` in the preceding statement.

I assumed that I have something wrong coded within the repository class so I attempted to used `@Autowired private IllegalWordRepository illegalWordRepository` inside a `@Service` annotated class and suprisingly it is injected there properly (e.i. not `null`):

```
// IllegalWordService.java
@Service
public class IllegalWordService {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IllegalWordService.class);
    
    @Autowired
    private IllegalWordRepository illegalWordRepository;

    public IllegalWord generate(String word) {
        log.debug("illegalWordRepository is null? " + (illegalWordRepository == null));
        // Returns "illegalWordRepository is null? false"
        
        IllegalWord illegalWord = new IllegalWord();
        illegalWord.setWord(word);
        
        illegalWordRepository.save(illegalWord);
        // Didn't encounter a NullPointerException here.

        return illegalWord;
    }
}
```

Therefore, I guess nothing is wrong with the `IllegalWordRepository` repository class. It's just that it is not injected in `NotContainingIllegalWordsValidator` validator class as I intended it to be with the `@Autowired` annotation (if that is how `@Autowired` annotation was intended to function even, I am sorry I am new in Spring Framework.).

If there is a proper approach on how to perform a @Entity query inside a `ConstraintValidator` instance, please tell me.

Related unanswered SO question: [Inject Repository inside ConstraintValidator with Spring 4 and message interpolation configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46594706/4043409)

---

**Failed Attempt:**

I tried to annotate the `NotContainingIllegalWordsValidator` class with `@Configurable` annotation, like so:

```
@Configurable(autowire=Autowire.BY_NAME, preConstruction=true)
public class NotContainingIllegalWordsValidator implements ConstraintValidator<NotContainingIllegalWords, Object> {
```

but the `illegalWordRepository` property remains `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Your validator is not initialized by Spring, you can't inject anything into it. You'd have to access the `ApplicationContext` through a static variable.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

  private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
  }
  public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
    return applicationContext;
  }
}
```

And in your `ConstraintValidator`:

```
public class NotContainingIllegalWordsValidator implements ConstraintValidator<NotContainingIllegalWords, Object> {
  public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext cxt) {
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = MyApplication.getApplicationContext();
    IllegalWordRepository illegalWordRepository = applicationContext.getBean(IllegalWordRepository.class);
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58126094/7598851) to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58088188):

The minimum setup for @Autowired to work properly in ConstraintValidator implementation is to have this bean in a Spring @Configuration:

```
@Bean
public Validator defaultValidator() {
    return new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
}
```

This is the [demo](https://github.com/Martin-BG/Autowired-in-ConstraintValidator) project